# Proof of convergence of a recursive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, faq

How do I prove that

$x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot (x_n + x_{n+1})$

$x_1=1$

$x_2=2$

is convergent?

Comment: Do you have an initial value? It will make things considerably easier

Comment: The sequence is defined by two initial values, but the proof of convergence depends only on the assumption that they are both real numbers.

Comment: yeah I updated my question

Comment: This is a recurrence relation of second order, so it's solvable. This could be useful: http://people.uncw.edu/tompkinsj/133/recursion/homogeneous.htm

Comment: I see, but doesn't exist a simpler way to solve it?

Comment: If you're asking me, I consider one quadratic equation and one 2x2 linear system to be pretty simple...

Comment: We could work out @Poppy 's result. Assume $a_n = a^n$ then:

Comment: $$a^{n+2} = 1/2 a^{n+1} + 1/2 a^{n} \rightarrow 2a^2 - a - 1 = 0. $$ Thus: $$ a = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4}}{4} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}$$ Note that $$ 2 < \sqrt{5} <3 \rightarrow |\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{4}| \le 1 $$ Thus as n approaches infinity this expression approaches 0 (a much stronger result)

Comment: Thank you now it is pretty clear!

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, actually that quadratic factors into $(2a+1)(a-1)$.  The square root portion in the quadratic formula is $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot2\cdot(-1)}=\sqrt{1+8}$.

Comment: oooh! that is very important

Comment: @BarryCipra I believe that means either the value sometimes may converge, and other times may shuffle around a bunch of values all of which have the same absolute value

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, no, you always converge to $(2x_2+x_1)/3$, which is the coefficient $r$ that matches up for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $x_n=r1^n+s(-1/2)^n$.

Answer (score 15):

Hint: how does $x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}$ relate to $x_{n+1} - x_n$?

Comment: This is by far the most efficient solution; it does not even require initial conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

$$x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{2}(x_n + x_{n+1}) $$

It follows that if

$$ x_n \le x_{n+1} $$

$$ x_n \le x_{n+2} \le x_{n+1} $$

Or if:

$$ x_n \ge x_{n+1} $$

Then:

$$ x_n \ge x_{n+2} \ge x_{n+1} $$

We note that equality only occurs if

$$ x_n = x_{n+1}$$

Thus consider the difference

$$ |x_{n+1} - x_n| = r $$

It then follows that

$$ |x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| = \frac{r}{2}$$

(Verify this for the case of $x_{n+2} > x_{n+1}$ vs. $x_{n+2} < x_{n+1}$)

Thus

$$ |x_{n+k} - x_{n+k-1}| = \frac{r}{2^{k-1}} $$

(Verify this by induction)

Therefore as k approaches infinity

$$ |x_{n+k} - x_{n+k-1}| \rightarrow 0 $$

Comment: I'm missing the link between $x_n=x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n+1} - x_n=r$, sorry

Comment: I just assume that they have a distance r, I don't say what that distance is

Comment: So r is not a fixed value, and it can be arbitrary, the fact is that it is finite

Comment: The two lines aren't explicitly connected, they are just highlighting some aspects of the problem (playing with it before I get the solution)

Comment: mmm ok, now i'm missing why $\frac{r}{2^{k-1}}$..

Comment: Try to reason this one out, what happens every time you calculate: $x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1} + x_{n})$. You are taking the average of the previous two values

Comment: Thus you know that $x_{n+2}$ will be midway between $x_{n+1}, x_{n}$

Comment: Therefore if the distance between $x_{n+1}, x_{n}$ is r, the distance between $x_{n+2}, x_{n+1}$ is now $\frac{r}{2}$

Comment: Each time you move up to $x_{n+3}$, $x_{n+4}$ ... $x_{n+k}$ your distance between the current term and the most recent term is HALF the previous distance, yielding $r$, $\frac{r}{2}$ ... $\frac{r}{2^{k-1}}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I think I got it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y_n \equiv x_n - \frac{x_0-x_1}{2}$$
Then it is easy to see that 
$$y_0 = \frac{x_0-x_1}{2} \\
y_1 = \frac{x_1-x_0}{2} = - y_0
$$
and with a wee bit of algebra, the relation 
$x_{n+2}= \frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_{n+1}$ becomes
$$y_{n+2}= \frac{1}{2}(y_n+y_{n+1})$$

But because $y_1 = -y_0$ the behavior of $y_n$ is easy to see:
$$
y_0 = y_0\\y_1 = -y_0
y_2 = 0 \\
y_3 = -\frac{1}{2} y_0 \\
y_4 = -\frac{1}{4} y_0 \\
y_5 = -\frac{3}{8} y_0 \\
y_6 = -\frac{5}{16} y_0 \\
y_7 = -\frac{11}{32} y_0 \\
$$
and in general, it is easy to show by induction that for $n > 3$
$$y_n = -\left( \frac{2}{3} + \frac{(-1)^{n-1} }{3\cdot 2^{n-2}} \right) y_0 $$
the limit of $y_n$ is always $\frac{2}{3}$
Then $x_n$ is obtained by adding back the average of $x_0$ and $x_1$ so it too has a finite limit.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @RobertIsrael,

$$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}=-\frac12(x_{n+1}-x_n).$$

The first order differences decrease geometrically so that their sum converges.

Comment: You can even tell that this sum is $2(x_2-x_1)/3$, so convergence is to $(2x_2+x_1)/3$.

Comment: @Sorry for asking: I see that the sum is equal to $2(x_2-x_1)/3$ so I get convergence to $2(x_2-x_1)/3$ and not to $(2x_2+x_1)/3$ (as it is the correct result) as follows: \begin{align}\lim_{N\to+\infty}x_{N+1}&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}\\&=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1/2)^n(x_2-x_1)\\&=\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac23(x_2-x_1)(1-(-1/2)^N)=\frac23(x_2-x_1)\end{align} Thanks. Edit: Is it only that I have to start from $n=1$ instead of $n=0$?

Comment: $x_5=\cdots x_5-x_4+x_4-x_3+x_3-x_2+x_2-x_1+x_1=\left(\cdots\left(-\frac12\right)^4+\left(-\frac12\right)^3+\left(-\frac12\right)^2+\left(-\frac12\right)\right)(x_2-x_1)+x_1$

Comment: Of course. Sorry for bothering you for something so trivial. Sometimes, I just get stacked with something that is obvious. Thanks anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

If $x_{n+1}=x_n$ then $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}$ and by induction the sequence is constant, thus convergent.

If $x_{n+1}\ne x_n$ and w.l.o.g. $x_{n+1} > x_n$ then $x_{n+1} > x_{n+2} > x_n$. This makes each pair of adjacent terms closer than previous pair:
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|<|x_{n+1}-x_n|$$
Additionally, each term is a midpoint of the range defined by two preceding terms, so each pair distance is a half of the previous pair distance:
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|= \frac 12 |x_{n+1}-x_n| = \frac 1{2^n} |x_2-x_1|$$
so the sequence is Cauchy, which implies (in $\Bbb R$) it's convergent.

You can also note that the subsequences of every other term are monotone: $(x_{2i+1})_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing and bounded by $x_2$, while $(x_{2i})_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing and bounded by $x_1$, so they are both convergent (however that alone does not prove $(x_n)$ is convergent).

**EDIT**

Let $d = x_2 - x_1$, then:

$\begin{align}
x_{2n+1} & = x_1 + d\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{2^{2i-1}} \\
x_{2n+2} & = x_2 - d\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{2^{2i}}
\end{align}$

For $n=0$ both sums are empty and expressions result in $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively.

For $n\to\infty$ both sums are geometric series with ratio $\tfrac14$, so:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{2n+1} = x_1 + d\frac {\frac 12}{1-\frac 14} = x_1 + \frac23d$
$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{2n+2} = x_2 - d\frac {\frac 14}{1-\frac 14} = x_2 - \frac13d$

so they are equal, thus

$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \frac13 x_1 + \frac23 x_2$